# how to proper insert a click event under mouseleave function using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a Mouse leave function and when i leave the specified div and do a mouse click out side of it then it trigger the event i needed.

This is what my code is what i have done but somehow it doesn't work as i have set it to be.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#Side-Div1').bind('mouseleave', function() {
            $('body').click(function(e){
                if(e.target.className !== '#Side-Div1'){
                    if($('#Side-Div1').is(":visible")){
                           $('.side-nav').fadeToggle('fast','linear');
                           $('body').removeAttr('style');
                           $('html,body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
                    }
                }
            }        
        });
    })

</script>
```

Is there something i missed of is there a proper way of logical set to do this event in one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $("#Side-Div1");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
       alert('Do whatever you want.');
        
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Side-Div1"><p>Click here or outside this to test this functionality</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please use below code if it works for you. It will work only when you will click outside this div and it will not work if you click on this div.Hope it will help you.

```
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
      var container = $("#Side-Div1");
      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
      {
       //alert('Do whatever you want.');
         $('.side-nav').fadeToggle('fast','linear');
         $('body').removeAttr('style');
         $('html,body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
      }
    });
```

Comment: here is the whole process if i click a certain button it opens up a div menu and so i wanted a function like if i leave hover that div and do a click it hides it the whole div 

i need a mouseleave function for this?

Comment: yes it should work for that..just run above snippet and do according your changes.It will work only when you will click outside that div/button.Just try to use above code i have tested same.

Comment: I have added your changes please check same and let me know if you are still facing this issue and accept if its working fine.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR BIG THANKS IT REALLY WORKS WELL I JUST ADDED A CONDITION IF DIV IS HIDDEN DONT SHOW.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
 $('#Side-Div1').mouseleave(function() {
```

Here is the official Documentation with an example:
https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Edit: I am not sure if it can work the way you want it to work.

Comment: Yes it works but i wanted to add a click event so that the flow would be if a i leave the div it doesn't hide immediately but if a i do a click outside the div then it hides the div

Comment: Cann you add the html code? So i can try finding a solution.
And maybe the css

Answer (score 0):

As your jquery selector $('#Side-Div1') then Side-Div1 must be an ID not class name. For select element by class, it should be:

```
$('.Side-Div1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply bind the mouseleave event to a boolean variable and keep the click event attached to the body like so:

```js
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")
var hasMouseLeft = false;


banner.mouseleave(function() {
  hasMouseLeft = true;
  console.log(hasMouseLeft)
})

$('body').click(function() {
  if (hasMouseLeft) {
    // do your magic here
    alert('Mouse has left the div !')
    hasMouseLeft = false;
  } else {
    // do something else or return
    return;
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```